# What is the reason I have to compile tailwind css on my own

Tags: css, tailwind-css

First of all I get that after I install with npm/x I can add my own rules then compile and end up with a single sheet, which is awesome. Other than this reason, is there any other reason why I should have to compile it myself? I mean, if the eventual installation process ends up with a .css file which I then add to my , why not just have a downloadable fully-featured css file as an installation option alongside the other installation options it provides? They do have a CDN, but the docs specifically mention that it is meant for dev purposes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can generate different tailwind css depending on your setup. For instance you can add theming with different color schemes, or spacing for margins. Also you can use the @apply rule directly in your sass files allowing you to write css shorthand.

@apply example:

```
 .btn-primary {
    @apply py-2 px-4 bg-blue-500 text-white font-semibold rounded-lg shadow-md hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-400 focus:ring-opacity-75;
  }
```

This gets compiled to

```
.btn-primary {
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    ...
}
```

If you aren't using any of these things, there's literally no good reason to include it in your build process. Tailwind acknowledges this and made it easier to import the library adhoc using their cdn. It's a js import to be more compatible in some environments.

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```